# excel 2016 exchange value automatically to ="*value*" in other cell

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have to exchange value in one cell to `="\*value\*"`

That is the only way that I found to make `=countif` and `=sumif` formula work.

At the moment the only solution that I found is to type `="**"` manually and it is a disaster. Is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First hi-light the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range, DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Formula = "=" & DQ & r.Value & DQ
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you want the asteriks in the formula, use this instead:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range, DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Formula = "=" & DQ & "*" & r.Value & "*" & DQ
    Next r
End Sub
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: I think you may have been misled by markdown's treatment of the * character. I edited the question to allow it to appear as the OP typed, ie ="\*value\*" rather than italicised ="*value*"

Comment: @Tetsujin  Good catch!  I made the edit.

Comment: Lovely! Have a +1 from me :)

Comment: @user904363  thank you for the feedback